# Why are AMD's graphics drivers not working?

Tags: rhel, drivers, amd-graphics, radeon

I'm having a problem getting the proprietary AMD graphics drivers working on RHEL 6.9 with a Radeon HD 8670 card.

Output from `lspci | grep -i VGA`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland XT [Radeon HD 8670 / R7 250/350] (rev 83)
```

If I set `export LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose` and run `glxgears`, I get the following output:

```
libGL: DRI3 is disabled, try running in DRI2 mode. xorg version is 0
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/X11R6/lib32/modules/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/X11R6/lib32/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/X11R6/lib32/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/X11R6/lib32/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib32/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib32/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib32/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib32/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server "localhost:10.0"
  after 25161 requests (38 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

I installed the proprietary AMD drivers from [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-RedHat-Install.aspx) and `yum list installed | grep amd` shows the following:

```
amdgpu-pro.x86_64                  17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
amdgpu-pro-dkms.noarch             17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
amdgpu-pro-lib32.x86_64            17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
glamor-egl-amdgpu-pro.x86_64       1.18.3-414273.el6       @amdgpu-pro-local    
libdrm-amdgpu-pro.i686             1:2.4.70-414273.el6     @amdgpu-pro-local    
libdrm-amdgpu-pro.x86_64           1:2.4.70-414273.el6     @amdgpu-pro-local    
libegl-amdgpu-pro.i686             17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
libegl-amdgpu-pro.x86_64           17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
libgbm-amdgpu-pro.i686             17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
libgbm-amdgpu-pro.x86_64           17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
libgbm-amdgpu-pro-base.noarch      17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
libgl-amdgpu-pro.i686              17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
libgl-amdgpu-pro.x86_64            17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
libgl-amdgpu-pro-appprofiles.x86_64
                               17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
libgl-amdgpu-pro-dri.i686          17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
libgl-amdgpu-pro-dri.x86_64        17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
libgl-amdgpu-pro-ext.x86_64        17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
libgles-amdgpu-pro.i686            17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
libgles-amdgpu-pro.x86_64          17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
libopencl-amdgpu-pro.i686          17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
libopencl-amdgpu-pro.x86_64        17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
libopencl-amdgpu-pro-clinfo.x86_64 17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
libopencl-amdgpu-pro-icd.i686      17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
libopencl-amdgpu-pro-icd.x86_64    17.10-414273.el6        @amdgpu-pro-local    
xorg-x11-drv-amdgpu-pro.x86_64     1:1.2.99-414273.el6     @amdgpu-pro-local
```

MESA is also installed as shown by `yum list installed | grep mesa`:

```
mesa-dri-drivers.x86_64            11.0.7-4.el6            @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201604140956.x86_64/6.8
mesa-dri-filesystem.x86_64         11.0.7-4.el6            @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201604140956.x86_64/6.8
mesa-dri1-drivers.x86_64           7.11-8.el6              @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201604140956.x86_64/6.8
mesa-libEGL.x86_64                 11.0.7-4.el6            @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201604140956.x86_64/6.8
mesa-libGL.x86_64                  11.0.7-4.el6            @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201604140956.x86_64/6.8
mesa-libGL-devel.x86_64            11.0.7-4.el6            @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201604140956.x86_64/6.8
mesa-libGLU.x86_64                 11.0.7-4.el6            @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201604140956.x86_64/6.8
mesa-libGLU-devel.x86_64           11.0.7-4.el6            @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201604140956.x86_64/6.8
mesa-libGLw.x86_64                 6.5.1-10.el6            @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201604140956.x86_64/6.8
mesa-libGLw-devel.x86_64           6.5.1-10.el6            @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201604140956.x86_64/6.8
mesa-libgbm.x86_64                 11.0.7-4.el6            @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201604140956.x86_64/6.8
mesa-libxatracker.x86_64           11.0.7-4.el6            @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201604140956.x86_64/6.8
mesa-private-llvm.x86_64           3.6.2-1.el6             @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201604140956.x86_64/6.8
```

The above output was obtained while logged into the system remotely from a Windows PC running X-Win32. On the system console, the usual GUI login screen does not appear on the default TTY. The usual text-only terminal login screen is displayed when switched to one of the other TTYs (`Ctrl + Alt + F2`, etc.).

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` has the following messages that appear to be relevant to the problem:

```
[    77.343] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    77.359] (II) Loading /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    77.648] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    77.648]    compiled for 1.17.0, module version = 1.0.0
[    77.648]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 9.0
[    77.648] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    77.648] (II) LoadModule: "amdgpu"
[    77.648] (II) Loading /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
[    77.684] (II) Module amdgpu: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    77.684]    compiled for 1.17.4, module version = 1.2.99
[    77.684]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    77.684]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    77.684] (II) AMDGPU: Driver for AMD Radeon:
    All GPUs supported by the amdgpu kernel driver
[    77.684] (++) using VT number 1

[    77.692] (II) [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
[    77.692] (II) AMDGPU(0): ShareFD: disabled
[    77.692] (DB) AMDGPU(0): open fd=8
[    77.693] (EE) AMDGPU(0): amdgpu_device_initialize failed
[    77.693] (EE)
[    77.693] (EE) Backtrace:
[    77.726] (EE) 0: /usr/bin/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x51) [0x7f3ddb8b8a91]
[    77.726] (EE) 1: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x7f3ddb6eb000+0x1d2109) [0x7f3ddb8bd109]
[    77.726] (EE) 2: /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f3ddae5a000+0xf7e0) [0x7f3ddae697e0]
[    77.726] (EE) 3: /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so (0x7f3dd5ae4000+0xd172) [0x7f3dd5af1172]
[    77.726] (EE) 4: /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so (0x7f3dd5ae4000+0x7d78) [0x7f3dd5aebd78]
[    77.726] (EE) 5: /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so (0x7f3dd5ae4000+0x8112) [0x7f3dd5aec112]
[    77.726] (EE) 6: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x7f3ddb6eb000+0xbc0da) [0x7f3ddb7a70da]
[    77.726] (EE) 7: /usr/bin/Xorg (xf86CallDriverProbe+0x84) [0x7f3ddb77d7a4]
[    77.726] (EE) 8: /usr/bin/Xorg (xf86BusConfig+0x46) [0x7f3ddb77d836]
[    77.726] (EE) 9: /usr/bin/Xorg (InitOutput+0x8de) [0x7f3ddb78b93e]
[    77.726] (EE) 10: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x7f3ddb6eb000+0x5d595) [0x7f3ddb748595]
[    77.726] (EE) 11: /lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x7f3dd8916d1d]
[    77.726] (EE) 12: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x7f3ddb6eb000+0x47741) [0x7f3ddb732741]
[    77.726] (EE)
[    77.726] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
[    77.726] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[    77.726] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
```

Why aren't the graphics drivers working?

Comment: Also, what happens if you run dmesg | tail right after this crash?

Answer (score 1):

[The proprietary AMDGPU-PRO driver only supports new(ish) cards](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx), which does not seem to include your Radeon HD 8670.

The open driver is missing a library (obviously). The only two solutions I can think of are:

1. Reinstall the driver, and/or
2. Download and install all the packages that could possibly contain the necessary file

Personally I would start with option 1.

If both of these fail, in order of likeliness:

1. Your GPU is completely unsupported by either driver
2. Your RHEL install is broken
3. RHEL as a whole is broken

For the first one, look at changing your /etc/X11/xorg.conf to use one of the older radeon drivers (ati, radeohd, etc)

For the second two, submit a bug report

Comment: The driver release notes indicate that this driver is indeed supposed to support the Radeon HD 8600 product family [link](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx), so that rules out option 1. This was on a fresh install of RHEL, so I don't have any reason to suspect option 2. If I uninstall the AMD drivers and reboot, X11 works (but this won't meet the performance needs of the end user since they do 3D graphics intensive work). I'm not clear on what you are suggesting to change in the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file.

Comment: The OpenSource driver is able to handle most 3D-intensive work.  I would double-check that it doesn't meet the needs, FWIW.  Make sure you have `dkms` installed.